# Wrapping wires with nylon / wax string

Tags: wiring

In some applications I have seen a group or small bundle of wires wrapped with a black nylon and wax covered string.

I am making some small bundles of wires and would like to make the wraps instead of using small zip ties.

What is this wire wrapping called and where can I find instructions for this technique.

Thanks

Comment: You mean mesh sleeving?

Comment: Not mesh sleeving. It is a black string covered with wax, then it is hand wrapped/ tied / weaved around the bundle of wires.

Comment: It's called lacing cord, and Google will get you something like a quarter of a million hits.

Comment: There are right and wrong ways to do the lacing, I think the ARRL handbook illustrated the differences but may be misremembering my source.  While the methods look similar one of them can work loose easier than the others.

Answer (score 2):

I call it lacing cord, as does Digikey and their suppliers.  However, Digikey don't stock it from either supplier.

I learned to use it while working installing equipment in a telephone exchange as a summer job 50 years ago - doubt if it is used much any more...

Wikipedia has a [brief article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_lacing), with pictures showing examples.

If I recall correctly, the lacing cord I've used was flat, like a narrow ribbon, rather than round like a normal cord.  Presumably the flat ribbon was easier on the wire insulation than a normal round cord.

Comment: @JohnBanes: If you live in a boating area, look at marine suppliers for waxed sail twine - it should serve the purpose, and will be available in small quantities (but it is usually white.)

Comment: Here is the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_lacing

Comment: Mouser stocks it- not cheap at $55 US or so but a spool will last a long time.

Comment: I integrated the link provided by @JohnBanes into your post.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is known as 'wire lacing'.

Although this is an old technique, it is still used today in certain high-reliability applications. Down-hole tools is one of those applications.

It's easy to do. The following is a copy / paste of my refresher notes:

Definitions: Long End is Lacing Cord from spool, short end is just what it says.

Fold about 6" lacing cord, tuck fold under and around wire bundle, fold long line into a loop and tuck that loop through the first loop, then feed free end of short end through the 2nd loop. Pull short and long ends apart and orient knot where desired. Now pull tight. Thread short end into a simple knot with the long end and pull tight. Cut both lines about 1/4" above knot. Done!

It takes a couple of tries to get it right but it's dead-easy to do and to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has what you need:
[https://www.amazon.com/Waxed-Lacing-Tape-Spool-Black/dp/B005PQRLYC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005PQRLYC)

I prefer this method to ty-wraps

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Patrick. We don't recommend products and where to buy them on this site - you can see the site help for more on this. The link will die and your answer will become useless. It would be better to give the correct name for the product so that the OP can search for it. Note too that the question was asked three years ago.